# Why's this audit "rude or offensive"?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, review-audits

I recently passed this audit: https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/29799780.

The post was deleted as "spam or offensive":
[image: spam?]

But I only think it is opinion based. It asks:

> I'm Interested to Know what are the Best Opportunities in Market Research and Digital
> Marketing Field.

which is opinion based.

So why is this spam or offensive?

Comment: It's not "rude or offensive", it's spam. The question "Exists only to promote a product or service" from the description of the spam flag, which applies here.

Comment: If it has a link to its site without any reason, it's spam?

Comment: @Someone_who_likes_SE That's the exact definition of a spam flag...

Comment: Yes. A link to a site without any reason means the post exists only to get people to click on the link, which is spam.

Comment: This is as blatant as spam on SO gets... New account, excessive capitalization, off-topic question that really doesn't even ask anything, external link, buzzwords... A company that's supposedly located in the US, but that links through to an facebook page under a different name with a banner photo that was probably taken in India... But they're trustworthy as their site has logos of: IBM, 3M, Intel, Henkel and Airbus, ttly legit!

Comment: @Cerbrus The things you can learn if you allow yourself to go look, amazing.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Because it's unsolicited self-promotion. It contains a link and the question itself is blatantly off-topic, so it stands to reason that the question exists solely to promote a product.